# Extra blank space around markers in plots with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, markers

Is there a way to remove extra white space around markers in matplotlib with Python ?

Example:

[image: Image with example]

I used the following:

```
plt.xkcd(randomness=100,scale=2,length=800)
```

Without this style, there is **no extra** white space. So, I suppose it's the style which change this.

I tried everything related to markers in this page but nothing change about this extra white space :
[matplotlib.lines.Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_marker)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try adding `, ec='none', lw=0` to the plot

Comment: Thank for your answer.
When you say 'adding' is adding to which part of the plot ?

Comment: When I add `edgecolor=None` I get `'Line2D' object has no property 'edgecolor'`.

I make the plot with :
`axes = plt.gca()

axes.plot(data['col_1'],data['col_2']),
            '-',color='red',label='Mean',linewidth=.75)`